# Angular2: Global variable not getting populated after backend api call in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, typescript

Am trying to populate an object `array` declared globally inside a `component` to be used in another function within same `component` but it's not getting populated.

The browser network tab shows the data in `response` to the `http` call but when I try to access the array, it shows `undefined`.

Here is what am trying:

```
myArray: MyObject[];
requestPath: string;
one: string;
two: string;
three: string;
four: string;

ngOnInit() {

     this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
     this.one = params['one'];
     this.two = params['two'];
     this.three = params['three'];
     this.four = params['four'];

    this.requestPath = this.getRequestPath(this.one,this.two,this.three,this.four);

    this.http.get(this.requestPath)  //returns a json data
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            data => { this.myArray = data;
        },
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('inside comparator oninit'));
    });
    this.add(this.myArray);
 }
```

And when I try to access it inside `add` function:

```
add(event){
   alert("data is: "+event);
}
```

I get `data is undefined` in the alert which means variable is not getting populated with the data fetched.

What is the right way to do this? What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are calling an Asynchronous call so you must need to call your method when async call finishes. So you need to call your function inside the subscribe call like this.

Try this-

```
        .subscribe(
            data => { 
                    this.myArray = data;
                    this.add(this.myArray);
        },
```

Comment: This is because outside the subscribe , it will call your method first and you get response after the call so you will get undefined

Comment: But shouldn't it populate the data inside subscribe and make it usable to entire component

Comment: I mean, when i have assigned the returned data to a global variable, it should ideally have that value to be used wherever I need. Isn't it?

Comment: You are right but Angular will assign data after your method is being called as this is async call and it will result after your normal/sync call.

Comment: so you need to call method when Angular will assign data to global variable then call your method

Answer (score 1):

You need to call inside the subscribe,

```
.subscribe(
        data => { this.myArray = data;
        this.add(this.myArray);
 }
```